# Inappropriate value for attribute "vpc_id": string required

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am setting my first terraform target groups and currently stuck in the middle.

> This is my resource code

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "ami_tg" {
  name     = "ami-lb-tg-${substr(uuid(), 0, 3)}"
  port     = var.tg_port
  protocol = var.tg_protocol
  vpc_id   = var.vpc_id
  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = var.elb_healthy_threshold
    unhealthy_threshold = var.elb_unhealthy_threshold
    timeout             = var.elb_timeout
    interval            = var.elb_interval
  }
}
```

Obviously I passed over to my variable.tf file

```
variable "tg_port" {}
variable "tg_protocol" {}
variable "elb_healthy_threshold" {}
variable "elb_unhealthy_threshold" {}
variable "elb_timeout" {}
variable "elb_interval" {}
variable "vpc_id" {}
```

Then added to my root/main.tf module file

```
   module "alb" {
  source                  = "./alb"
  tg_port                 = 80
  tg_protocol             = "HTTP"
  vpc_id                  = module.networking.vpc_id
  elb_healthy_threshold   = 2
  elb_unhealthy_threshold = 2
  elb_timeout             = 3
  elb_interval            = 30
}
```

But I keep getting the below error whenever I run terraform plan ;

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on alb/main.tf line 16, in resource "aws_lb_target_group" "ami_tg":
  16:   vpc_id   = var.vpc_id
    |----------------
    | var.vpc_id is object with 19 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "vpc_id": string required.
```

Any suggestions here will be appreciated

Comment: What exactly is `module.networking.vpc_id`? How is it defined in your `module.networking`?

Comment: That means my vpc resource code  defined in  the networking directory  thus passing to tg directory since I am created a new directory which in this case is the alb                  #------ networking/main.tf...


resource "aws_vpc" "HH_vpc" {
  cidr_block           = var.vpc_cidr
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true

  tags = {
    Name = "HH-vpc ${random_integer.random.id}

Comment: But how the `output` vpc_id is defined?

Comment: #---networking/outputs.tf

output "vpc_id" {
  value = aws_vpc.HH_vpc
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output:

```
output "vpc_id" { 
    value = aws_vpc.HH_vpc
}
```

returns **entire** `HH_vpc` object, not only its id. To return only id it should be:

```
output "vpc_id" { 
    value = aws_vpc.HH_vpc.id
}
```

Comment: That's what I was unable to figure out - thanks for your help

Comment: A tip that can help catch this sort of mistake closer to its cause is to make sure to always declare the expected type for each of your variables. For this particular variable you'd do that by writing `type = string` inside the `variable "vpc_id"` block. In that case Terraform would've reported the problem inside the `module "alb"` block, which is still not directly at the cause but at least reduces the parts of the configuration you need to review while debugging.